# SEOmatic Errors in Debug - Can they be fixed?

Tags: seo, plugin-seomatic

SEOmatic throws up a lot of errors in the debug. Most of the errors seem to be with fields I haven't filled in as they are not required like Facebook App ID etc.

Is this an issue or do I just ignore? Disabling the plugin reduced the number of database requests to 50 instead of the 140 being shown and improved the speed slightly so just wondering if the errors are creating performance issues?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These errors will only appear with `devMode` on, and they are intended to help you diagnose potential problems with the meta tags and other information that you are rendering.

These are all soft errors, though. You can safely ignore them if they are a result of you not filling in things that you don't intend to fill in.

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-seomatic#meta-object-validation